# call a method from an inner Method

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I'm using ag-grid and reacting to some events I want to access to methods defined in the current componnet something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'whatever',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

...

methodToCall(params : any){
  return 1;
}


gridOptions = {

  onCellValueChanged: function(params : DynamicComponentParams){  
       *//I want from here to call the method "methodToCall"*
       this.methodToCall(null); *//this doesn't work....*

  },


 ..... 

};
```

So from the method: "onCellValueChanged" I need to call the method "methodToCall", using this here is wrong because the scope is different, but then How do I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try arrow function `=>` like this -

```
onCellValueChanged = (params : DynamicComponentParams): void => {  
       *//I want from here to call the method "methodToCall"*
       this.methodToCall(null); *//this doesn't work....*

  },
```

Comment: It doesn't even compile

Comment: @navy1978 Change the colon after the method name to an equals sign.

Comment: @TheHeadRush yes you are right

Comment: Ok I was able to do it... Thank you ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
 onCellValueChanged: (params : DynamicComponentParams) { 
       let vari = this.methodToCall(null); 
  },
```

try like this